# Unity: Can't change SpriteResolver with script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with animation not working when I change sprites from Sprite Library Asset with a script. I don't know why animation not working but it work well when I change it in Unity Editor play mode.

[image: Unity Editor on Play Mode]

**Here my script below:**

```cs
private void SetClotherWithID(
     SpriteResolver spriteResolver,
     string category,
     string label)
{
    spriteResolver.SetCategoryAndLabel(category, label);
    spriteResolver.ResolveSpriteToSpriteRenderer();
}
```

I get `spriteResolver` from `GameObject`:

```cs
SetClotherWithID(footL.GetComponent<SpriteResolver>(),
     ConstUtils.CategoryFootL, ConstUtils.LabelFootLQ01);
```

Answer (score 0):

The labels are not Strings, They are floats, cause...well... unity right?
anyways, the only way i found was to make everything in layers of animators and update the parameters in editor via script, this way u can change them via code.
got it from here: https://harvtronix.com/blog/unity-how-to-use-a-sprite-resolver

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).